# AttributeError: 'TestOne' object has no attribute 'driver'

Tags: automated-testing, python, pytest

When I run my script it gives me this error,

**CONSOLE ERROR :**

```
"C:\Users\LENOVO L540\PycharmProjects\easyNeasypytest\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\_jb_pytest_runner.py" --path "C:/Users/LENOVO L540/PycharmProjects/easyNeasypytest"
Testing started at 3:39 PM ...
Launching pytest with arguments C:/Users/LENOVO L540/PycharmProjects/easyNeasypytest in C:\Users\LENOVO L540\PycharmProjects\easyNeasypytest

============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.9.1, pytest-6.2.2, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- C:\Users\LENOVO L540\PycharmProjects\easyNeasypytest\venv\Scripts\python.exe
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: C:\Users\LENOVO L540\PycharmProjects\easyNeasypytest
collecting ... collected 1 item

tests/test_e2e.py::TestOne::test_e2e FAILED                              [100%]
tests\test_e2e.py:13 (TestOne.test_e2e)
self = <tests.test_e2e.TestOne object at 0x000001BB1A4A5C40>

    def test_e2e(self):
>       action = ActionChains(self.driver)
E       AttributeError: 'TestOne' object has no attribute 'driver'

tests\test_e2e.py:15: AttributeError


Assertion failed


Assertion failed


================================== FAILURES ===================================
______________________________ TestOne.test_e2e _______________________________

self = <tests.test_e2e.TestOne object at 0x000001BB1A4A5C40>

    def test_e2e(self):
>       action = ActionChains(self.driver)
E       AttributeError: 'TestOne' object has no attribute 'driver'

tests\test_e2e.py:15: AttributeError
============================== warnings summary ===============================
utilities\BaseClass.py:4
  C:\Users\LENOVO L540\PycharmProjects\easyNeasypytest\utilities\BaseClass.py:4: PytestUnknownMarkWarning: Unknown pytest.mark.usefixture - is this a typo?  You can register custom marks to avoid this warning - for details, see https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/mark.html
    @pytest.mark.usefixture("setup")

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html
=========================== short test summary info ===========================
FAILED tests/test_e2e.py::TestOne::test_e2e - AttributeError: 'TestOne' objec...
======================== 1 failed, 1 warning in 0.15s =========================

Process finished with exit code 1


Assertion failed

Assertion failed
```

**test_e2e.py**

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

from utilities.BaseClass import BaseClass


class TestOne(BaseClass):

    def test_e2e(self):
        action = ActionChains(self.driver)
        menu = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("li[class='list-inline-item cart-btn drop mr-0'] a[class='btn btn-link border-none']")
        time.sleep(2)
        action.move_to_element(menu).perform()
        childmenu = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Login')]")
        action.move_to_element(childmenu).click().perform()
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("saniaaslam987@gmail.com")
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("123456")
        self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name("button").click()
        print(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Logged In Successfully.')]").text)
        time.sleep(3)
        print("***********************Scrolled down starts***************")
        for i in range(10):
            time.sleep(0.5)
            self.driver.execute_script(" window.scrollBy(0, 350);")
            print("scrolling time: " + str(i))
        print("*************************scrolling down end**********************")
        print("**************************************Scrolled up starts****************")
        for i in range(10):
            time.sleep(0.5)
            self.driver.execute_script(" window.scrollBy(0,-350);")
            print("scrolling time: - " + str(i))
        print("**************************************Scrolled up End ****************")
        time.sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='keyword']").send_keys("product")
        self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[class*='search-form__submit form-btn form-btn--2']").click()
        time.sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h5[contains(text(),'Product Dummy 7')]").click()
        self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 200)")
        self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("checkmark").click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[class='btn btn-secondary btn-lg font-ubuntu']").click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='https://aujtravels.com/easyneasy/cart']//img").click()
        time.sleep(1)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//label[contains(@class,'checkbox-design m-auto p-0 d-inline-block m-checkbox')]//span[contains(@class,'checkmark')]").click()
        time.sleep(1)
        self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#plusButtonId5").click()
        time.sleep(1)
        print(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Cart updated successfully')]").text)
        time.sleep(3)
        self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#proceed_btn").click()
        time.sleep(1)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'+ Add New Address')]").click()
        time.sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Add New Address')]").click()
        time.sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#name").send_keys("Arsal")
        time.sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("phone").send_keys("12345678901")
        time.sleep(2)
        self. driver.find_element_by_id("address").send_keys("8")
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='street']").send_keys("ghang Road ")
        cities = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#city_id"))
        cities.select_by_visible_text('Karachi')
        area = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='district_id']"))
        time.sleep(2)
        area.select_by_index(1)
        self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#zip_code").send_keys("39350")
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='shipping_address']").click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#add_address_btn").click()
        # print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Address added successfully')]").text)
        self.driver.get_screenshot_as_file("screen.png")
        next = self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("Payment Methods")
        self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", next)
        time.sleep(1)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Delete')]").click()
        alert = self.driver.switch_to.alert
        print(alert.text)
        alert.accept()
        time.sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("Add Payment Method").click()
        time.sleep(2)
        dropdown = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='payment_method']"))
        dropdown.select_by_visible_text('Debit')
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='name']").send_keys("Arsal")
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("card_digit").send_keys("1234")
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("expiry").send_keys("07/25")
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='add_payment_btn']").click()
        time.sleep(1)
        self.driver.refresh()
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Account Settings')]").click()
        time.sleep(1)

        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Edit')]").click()
        time.sleep(1)
        # driver.switch_to.frame("automation_1")
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("tax_number").send_keys("123456789")
        time.sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("profile_image").send_keys("C:\\Users/LENOVO L540/Downloads/bird.jpg")
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Update']").click()
        print("*************************************Profile Updated*******************")
```

**Conftest.py**

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def setup(request):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.get("https://aujtravels.com/easyneasy/")
    driver.maximize_window()
    request.cls.driver = driver
    yield
    driver.close()
```

**BaseClass.py**

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.usefixture("setup")
class BaseClass:****
    pass
```

I'm not able to understand what this error is and how to fix it. Please help me with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.driver
```

means driver of this object and your code cannot find any variable called driver for that object instance.

There is no instance variable driver:

```
def test_e2e(self):
    action = ActionChains(self.driver)
```

do something like **(if baseclass has a driver class variable)**

```
from utilities.BaseClass import BaseClass 

     driver = BaseClass.driver
```

**This is a really good article to understand python inheritance basics:**

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects

you should call *init*

Comment: The link seems to be broken .

Comment: @MateMrše Thanks updated it

Answer (score 0):

One way to bypass this issue is the use of ***request*** in test parameter.ie:

```
def test_e2e(self, request):
self.driver = request.cls.driver
...
```

This way you can execute the tests.
Note: the import should be better if provided from the code root location i.e

```
from utilities.BaseClass import BaseClass >>> from src.utilities.BaseClass import BaseClass
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to run your code using py. test "filename" not with the "run button"

else you will get this error.